# Word Automation Services: Wrong font in created PDF

Tags: pdf, word-automation

We migrated a solution that uses Word Automation Services to convert Word document in PDF files from a SharePoint 2010 farm to a SharePoint 2010 SP1 + CU Feb 2013 farm.

The solution still works an creates PDF files, but: A text in thats in a special font in the original Word document is translated to Arial in the resulting PDF.

On the pre SP1 farm, the conversion works without losing the font. And yes, the font is installed on all machines of the SP1 farm, I double checked ...

What can have caused this? Do we have to register the font in Word Automation Services or something like that?

Comment: If the font is installed and is a true type font then after applying the patch is the server is rebooted it should work.

Comment: The operator installed the wrong font ... after installing the right one and restarting the server, it worked :-S ... I'm closing this question ...

Comment: Well I can't close the question while the bounty is running ...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Arial may be the embedded font in the system. Microsoft has a hotfix package for this. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2596581

Comment: No, it was just a mistake on our side (see my last comments) ... thx anyway.

Comment: Yea I read that after I posted the response. However I thought it was a good answer if someone else had the issue.