# Word Automation Services converting wingdings to the wrong symbol

Tags: word, pdf, word-automation

Using word automation services to convert a Word document to a PDF I'm having a problem with how it's handling the wingdings font. The original document uses the symbol `0xE9` - described [here](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html) as `barb4up` and `0xEA` (`barb4down`) but after conversion, it appears in the PDF to be one of the ribbon arrows (`0xC9` and `0xCA`). I tried switching to the skinny arrows `0xE1` (`barb2up`) and `0xE2` (`barb2down`) but they seem to end up as one of the clock Wingdings.

Does anybody have any idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The server(s) making the conversions need to have the correct Wingdings fonts installed. Otherwise it can't recognize the character encoding and can't interpret the right output.

1. Install Wingdings font on the server(s) making conversions
2. Restart the server(s) making conversions
3. Try again

Reference: [Word Automation Services: Wrong font in created PDF](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73637/word-automation-services-wrong-font-in-created-pdf)